# Updating $rootScope of hosting app in widget

Tags: angularjs, widget, lazy-loading

Using [angular-widget](https://github.com/wix/angular-widget) we are hosting a lazily loaded angularjs app. I've created a service in the hosting application to expose a loading screen, that widgets can use to tell the hosting app to show/hide the loading screen.

The loading screen is triggered by setting `Loading` on `$rootScope` to `true`. The service simply exposes a `show()` and `hide()` method and keeps track of who asks for the loading screen, in case of multiple things asking for a loading screen at the same time.

When triggering the service in the *hosting* application, it works just fine. However, triggering the same service in the *hosted* application, it seems that the update to `$rootScope.Loading` *happens*, but the view in the hosting app doesn't update. I know the update is happening, because I put a $watch on `$rootScope.Loading` which *does* trigger, but like I said, the view doesn't update to reflect the change.

I've got a plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7hskrPayP2vyAkJEeIPX). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to add `widgetsProvider.addServiceToShare` to my config. Once that was added, the view started updating as expected.